# Closing an asp.net page from a div on the same page

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET page that contains a div that displays a button. When the button is pressed the div disappears leaving just the ASP.NET page (which is itself a popup from another larger asp.net page)

```
The ASP.NET ASPX is here:

<div id="UpdateErrDiv" runat="server" class="msgBox" style="z-index: 2000; width: 250px" visible="false">
            <div id="UpdateErrText" runat="server"></div>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="butCloseErrMsg" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="butClose_Click" Text="Close" />
</div>
```

The code-behind is here:

```
protected void butClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{        
    UpdateErrDiv.Visible = false;
}
```

How do I close down the op-up asp.net page after the div disappears?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to close the popup using Javascript.  You can use something like this:

```
protected void butClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{        
    UpdateErrDiv.Visible = false;
    Page.RegisterStartupScript("closeWindow", "window.close()", true);
}
```

Comment: I tried:ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "closeWindow", "window.close()", true); but its not working. Any ideas?

Comment: @user3374841 Describe not working. Do you receive a client side or server side error? Check your JavaScript console.

Comment: No error I could detect. The pop-up window (that the div is on) stays open.  No error thrown...

Comment: @user3374841 Have you viewed the source of your popup and checked if the javascript is being rendered?

Comment: I had a look - its not rendering. I'm i nthe F12 develoepr tools looking at the DOM explore and Degugger windows

Comment: It's working: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, GetType(), "ClosePopup", "window.close();", true);